# The caller does not have permission [403] Error - YouTube thumbnail

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to update YouTube video thumbnails via the data API.  Randomly I'm getting the error "The caller does not have permission [403]" for certain videos.
Things I've checked

- Confirmed I have access to the channel and the video is valid.
- Video is valid
- Thumbnail is valid

Does anyone else see this?